# Obtaining click coordinates in Android ListView OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview

Let's say, I have an Android ListView that I attached an OnItemClickListener to:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(...);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        [...]
```

When a certain item in the view is clicked, I can figure out the corresponding rectangle by getting the `view`'s dimensions. However, I would like to get the corresponding coordinates even more precisely to identify the point on the screen that the user actually clicked.

Unfortunately, the `OnItemClickListener` API does not seem to expose this information. Are there any alternative ways of getting hold of this detail (without proudly reinventing the wheel by implementing my own `ListView`)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I needed to do this also.  I set an OnTouchListener and an OnItemClickListener on the ListView.  The touch listener is fired first, so you can use it to set a variable which you can then access from your onItemClick().  It's important that your onTouch() returns false, otherwise it will consume the tap.  In my case, I only needed the X coordinate:

```
private int touchPositionX;

...

getListView().setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    touchPositionX = (int)event.getX();
    return false;
  }
});

getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (touchPositionX < 100) {
    ...
```